# How do I deploy the BIRT viewer (runtime) on heroku with my custom reports?

Tags: git, tomcat, heroku, birt

I see that heroku supports the deployment of tomcat apps from your own source code in git.  However, what if I have a war file that is pre-built (BIRT runtime engine) that I just need to deploy adjacent to my other apps so that reports can be linked against the database being managed by those other apps?  I have custom reports that would be deployed along with this war file.  It seems that the only information about this pertains to the deployment of a git repo containing the source for the app - in this case BIRT.  Seems like I would be just creating a lot of work for myself by being forced into this paradigm.

Comment: I wish there was a BIRT add-on in Heroku!

Comment: I have moved on and am now deploying my app on Linode.  It is much easier to work with and deploy in any manner you want.